# Python and C returning different values for algorithm

Tags: python, c, random

I am trying to implement the following c code for a Tausworthe random number generator in python. The code needs to generate random numbers within the range of 0 to 1. The c code is as follows:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/**** VERY IMPORTANT **** :
  The initial seeds z1, z2, z3, z4  MUST be larger than
  1, 7, 15, and 127 respectively.
****/

#define SEED 987654321

static uint32_t z1 = SEED, z2 = SEED, z3 = SEED, z4 = SEED;


double lfsr113 (void)
{
   uint32_t b;
   b  = ((z1 << 6) ^ z1) >> 13;
   z1 = ((z1 & 4294967294U) << 18) ^ b;
   b  = ((z2 << 2) ^ z2) >> 27;
   z2 = ((z2 & 4294967288U) << 2) ^ b;
   b  = ((z3 << 13) ^ z3) >> 21;
   z3 = ((z3 & 4294967280U) << 7) ^ b;
   b  = ((z4 << 3) ^ z4) >> 12;
   z4 = ((z4 & 4294967168U) << 13) ^ b;
   return (z1 ^ z2 ^ z3 ^ z4) * 2.3283064365386963e-10;
}
```

So far I have implemented this in python as:

```
#Tausworthe implementation
#define seeds
s0 = 987654321
s1 = 987654321
s2 = 987654321
s3 = 987654321
b=0

def Taus():        

    global s0
    global s1
    global s2
    global s3
    global b

    b =  (((s0 << 6 )^s0) >>13)
    print(s0)
    s0 = (((s0 & 4294967294)<<18) ^ b)

    b =  (((s1 << 2) ^ s1) >>27)
    s1 = (((s1 & 4294967288) << 2) ^ b)
    b =  (((s2 << 13) ^ s2) >> 21)
    s2 = (((s2 & 4294967280) << 7) ^b)
    b  = ((s3 << 3) ^ s3) >> 12;
    s3 = ((s3 & 4294967168) << 13) ^ b;

    return((s0 ^ s1 ^ s2^s3)* 2.3283064365386963e-10)
```

When I run the C code I get the first three values generated as 0.920278, 0.277765 and 0.564335. When I run my python implementation I get the first three values as 60479.92110524047, 168598.21778273885, 1344.2269172724336.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what I am doing wrong. The C implementation comes from the author of a paper on this specific Tausworthe generator and is therefore the correct one and when I run it produces the results I expect. I need to try and replicate these results in Python but I suspect the fact that C is strongly typed and that Python is not is maybe causing problems for me.

Any help or suggestions as to why my results are so off would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't shown any debugging attempts. Either step through both algorithms with a debugger and/or add debug print messages to show the intermediate steps each algorithm is taking. The difference should become quickly apparent.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend making `Taus` a class, and store the state in member variables, rather than globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python integers are not a fixed width; the C code is relying on any computation that exceeds 32 bits being implicitly truncated.

To make Python work the same way, you're going to need to add a lot of `& 0xFFFFFFFF`  operations to the code to explicitly mask the values back down to 32 bits. Specifically, you'll need them after every operation that could conceivably increase a value beyond 32 bits, which for this code looks like all the left shifts; I don't see any additions or multiplications at all, so it's just the left shifts you need fix up.

Comment: Or use [`ctypes.c_uint32`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_uint32).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: That kinda works, but you'd need to *constantly* rewrap and unwrap to do it; you can't actually do the math with `c_uint32` (it doesn't implement mathematical operations), so all it does is a virtual `& 0xFFFFFFFF`, which you then need to unpack (by accessing `.value`) to do anything useful with the result. It's also slower, `ctypes` wrappers are annoyingly slow to do anything with.

Comment: Good point, it's probably not worth the effort over just manually masking.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Lesson learnt - python integers are not fixed width!